# Choosing which function to call based on the architecture

Tags: c++, c, x86, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I'm working primarily in NASM, however I'm also making a C/C++ header file that uses `extern`s to import functions from NASM to the project. I'm worried about someone using the x64 NASM in a x86 environment. I know this isn't possible(to run x64 in x86) because of the invalid operand sizing errors I'm getting when I compile. I'm planning on re-making the project, but in x86, so it can work in either x86 or x64.

My trouble begins when declaring the `extern "C"` functions.

I want to keep a single function name(`openfile`, for example), but have the definition be based off of the x64 variant or the x86 variant, depending on whether the macro `arch_x64` or `arch_x86` is defined.

I can use preprocess for this, like the example below:

```cpp
#ifdef arch_x64
    int value = 1;
#elif arch_x86
    int value = 0;
#endif
```

and if I declare `arch_x64` in my source project, `value` is `1`.

I want to use this same method for the function `openfile`. Based on the architecture, the function *definition* should be either the x64 or x86.

I *could* do

```cpp
#ifdef arch_x64
    extern "C" void openfile64();
#elif arch_x86
    extern "C" void openfile32();
#endif

void openfile()
{
    #ifdef arch_x64
        openfile64(); // 64-bit version
    #elif arch_x86
        openfile32(); // 32-bit version
    #endif
};
```

and that'd work, but then the `openfile64` function is accessible, which could be confusing.

Is there a way to assign `openfile`'s definition to either the x64(`openfile64`) or x86(`openfile32`) version?

**EDIT**

I just now realized that Jan Schultke meant using a `.cpp` file or similar to hide `openfile64`. This could work, but I can't detect a `#define` across `.cpp` files. I'd need to send something down to the `.cpp` file that tells it what functions to set it as(or I'm thinking too much and there's a simpler way). That "something"(again, unles I'm thinking too hard) would also be exposed in the header file. I don't want to expose anything new besides the function `openfile`.

Comment: Why would `openfile64` be accessible? Couldn't you just define it internally in a single source file and not expose it in a header?

Comment: The method I did exposed `openfile64`. Although you're right that I could define it internally to not expose it. How would I do that?

Comment: If `openfile()` was defined in a source file, then everything inside the function wouldn't be visible in a header, including our reference to `openfile64`. As a result, there's also no need to ever declare or define `openfile64` in a header, and we can keep it "hidden". If you're worried about exposing it in the binary, you could also use something like `attribute__((always_inline))`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called ifunc (indirect function). It is a feature of the GNU/GCC toolchain that allows a developer to create multiple implementations of a given function and to select one of them at runtime using a **resolver** function. A function attribute is added to specify the resolver function. This is how correct implementation of glibc functions like memcpy/memmove is called for a particular microarchitecture. This is also supported by llvm toolchain.

References:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bifunc_007d-function-attribute-3095
- https://lpc.events/event/11/contributions/1103/attachments/832/1576/Puzzle%20for%20RISC-V%20ifunc.pdf
- https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/sparc/sparc64/multiarch/ifunc-memcpy.h.html

Comment: `ifunc` is for *runtime* dispatch based on CPU features (like supporting AVX).  It's known at compile time whether we're building for 32-bit x86 or x86-64, so you don't want or need the minor extra overhead of an indirect function call.  The resolver function would just be returning a constant, which is silly.

Answer (score 0):

Using your toolchain might be an alternative:

code_x86.cpp

```
#ifdef arch_x64
# error "wrong arch"
#endif

void openfile() // openfile32 implementation
{
    /*..*/ // 32-bit version
}
```

code_x64.cpp

```
#ifdef arch_x86
# error "wrong arch"
#endif

void openfile() // openfile64 implementation 
{
    /*..*/ // 64-bit version
}
```

and then include only files matching your architecture.